# quickfix sendToTarget and persistence

Tags: c++, quickfix

In a c++ quickfix server app, is there a way to call sendToTarget when the target session is not logged on, so that when the client possibly does logon later it will get all the messages that were "sent" since the its logon?

Comment: Did you use **PersistMessages** ?? And why would you do it, isn't it an extra work for your engine ??

Comment: Because it is necessary for the client to get all the messages. Am I not understanding your question/comment?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to see if quickfix provides methods to queue outbound messages. Or do I need to write my own. I would use this when a given session is not logged in.

Comment: @DumbCoder, how does the engines work in case of PersistMessages? how can they know if a message is send or not? do they require a confirmation from the client?

Answer (score 0):

By default, QuickFIX will store all outgoing messages in case they are requested later by the client. If the client detects a gap in the incoming sequence numbers they will request a message resend. If you send a message when the client is not connected it will be stored and the client will request a Resend at the next logon.